# Need recommandations for Cocoa Tutorials for programatic development of Mac applications

Tags: cocoa, macos

I am new to Mac OS application development. I am quite familiar with iPhone application development. But I am confused about creating windows, table views and other things in Mac application. I saw some tutorials teaching those things using IB. But I want to learn to do these programatically.

In iPhone we can create View Controller and add it to window or to a navigation controller which can be added to window. I need to know how to do similar things in Mac.  Can anyone suggest/recommend me some beginners tutorials which teach programmatic development of Mac applications..

Don't blame me for this simple/very-basic/whatever-you-think-worst-about-this-question question. I have been googling on this topic about a week now. I cant able to find what I need. I always appreciate your help.

Thanks everyone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's nothing magical about IB. it doesn't add any functionality apart from the ability to view and edit dynamic types in a WYSIWYG manner. it uses all the functionalities of the class interfaces, as well as some Cocoa internals (which are visible enough to you - things like bindings and archiving).

the biggest runtime difference lies in how objects (e.g. NSViews) are created. with nibs, you get nib unarchiving, rather than `[[MONView alloc] initWithFrame:r]`.

you really won't need much wrt tutorials if you're already comfortable with the language/patterns. typically, you'll just look for properties with the same name and define it there. additionally, you'll implement your own initWith methods, rather than NSCoder+awakeFromNib methods. it's really very simple once you understand how IB unarchives the nib.

so... as a starting point, i'd recommend converting functional nibs to functional programmatic implementations. along the way, you'll have to look up a few methods to understand how to manipulate and construct NSView graphs -- how to convert what you know in IB to source representations.

i really don't know of a specific resource, my point is that it is easier than you may believe. sure, there are a few pubs which demonstrate this briefly - but the ones i know of quickly demonstrate it in a few cases as proof of concept and then continue the tutorials using IB.

the best singular resource i know of for this is Cocoa Programming (Anguish/Buck/Yacktman) - perhaps that is dated or has been revised. the last rev i know of is from 2002.

lastly, you may get a lot of people telling you what a horrible idea it is to *not* use IB. if you want to do serious development and you already understand IB, i think it's a great skill and it is very useful for me - particularly for complex apps and large codebases. for simple apps, it doesn't matter much. i rarely create/use nibs - i just implement it programmatically in the majority of cases. i find it cleaner, faster, and less redundant. also, i have a ton of custom implementations and use objc++ so... IB isn't really that much help when you're that far from the mainline.

good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I know the use of IB. But, as a learner I always prefer to code myself to learn it better.

Comment: @Simon that's perfectly fine if you're taking it seriously. i consider it a mandatory skill for intermediate and advanced Cocoa devs. unfortunately, that's not the case as often as i'd hope. the docs are also helpful if you've questions about specific methods - they provide links to related sample code at the end of the listings, for specific methods and classes. however, the thoroughness, applicability, and quality of the samples may vary so internet searches are also very helpful. chances are, somebody's already questioned or solved problems which answers aren't readily evident to you.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. It will be fine even if I get the tutorial on how to create "Hello World" app programatically. I am struggling how to start to do everything programatically.